# How to get return value from remote ps script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using invoke-expression to call a remote script on another server. I was wondering how I can get the status code from that remote script to tell whether the script completes successfully or fails.

In fact, I am not sure whether invoke-expression will work for this return value, if it doesn't , is there any other way to work it around?

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Expression` is not recommended.  [PSScriptAnalyzer](http://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSScriptAnalyzer/1.6.0) will tell you [not to use this if you can avoid this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingInvokeExpression.md).

The typical way of getting a value from a remote system I'll demonstrate below.  The value must be serializable.

```
$session = New-PSSession # the rest of the command to establish the session
$value = Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {
   # Do work to get value in say variable $returnValue
   return $returnValue
}
```